# Issue with Background Events FullCalendar from php script JSON string

Tags: php, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to include a list of holidays as Background Events from a separate event source. "holidays.php" is one of my event sources. In month view, when I reach one of the holidays dates, there is no background event and my other events from different sources disappear! When I comment out "holidays.php" as an event source, there is no issues with other events. I'm guessing there's an issue with my json string?

**holidays.php**

```
<?php

$record[0]["title"]="Halloween Holiday";
$record[1]["title"]="Birthday";
$record[2]["title"]="December Day!";

$record[0]["date"]="2016-10-31T09:00:00";
$record[1]["date"]="2016-11-23T09:00:00";
$record[2]["date"]="2016-12-01T09:00:00";


for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {

    $event_array[] = array(
            'title' => $record[$i]['title'],
            'start' => $record[$i]['date'],
            'rendering' => 'background',
            'allDay' => false

    );


}

echo json_encode($event_array);


exit;

?>
```

**JSON string from holidays.php**

```
[{
    "title": "Halloween Holiday",
    "start": "2016-10-31T09:00:00",
    "rendering": "background",
    "allDay": false
}, {
    "title": "Birthday",
    "start": "2016-11-23T09:00:00",
    "rendering": "background",
    "allDay": false
}, {
    "title": "December Day!",
    "start": "2016-12-01T09:00:00",
    "rendering": "background",
    "allDay": false
}]
```

Comment: try adding end time... something like "end": "2016-10-31T12:00:00",

Comment: Same issue. I did not include and end as the holiday will run for that entire day.

Comment: but you have allDay:false .........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have an event with no end date if "allDay" is true.

If you want an event to run all day, then either

a) remove the time element from the start date and set `allDay: true`, OR

b) If the event genuinely starts at 09:00, as you've put in the data, then you'll need to add a corresponding end date before it will work. Note though that "background" events where `allDay : false` is set will not show up in the "Month" view, only in the week and day views.

Also, if you're still using the eventRender functionality from your previous question, any events with no end date will probably cause it to crash, because it checks every event and tries to use the "end" property in the calculation.